# Program for calculating size of folded towels

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I've been thinking about this for some time and now I'we decided to do It but i coudn't find anything on the internet that could help me even start. However, I'm facing a problem in my bathroom that I have few towels with really different dimensions and It looks ( sounds) like It's impossible to find a folding combination that will align all of them at once.
For example. I have these 4 different towels and I want a program to tell me which surface area is the common area for them and how to fold them to achieve that . [image: 4 different size towels]

Does anyone have an idea from where and how to start this?

Thanks!

Comment: To confirm - you want to fold all the towels so that they have the same dimensions? Also, what sorts of folds are allowed?

Comment: Do you have any specific folding rules? Otherwise, you can always fold a larger towel to match a smaller one.

Comment: Yes @templatetypedef that's right :)
And for the rules, or more precisely constrains, would be something like " same side cannot be folded more then 4 times" or ( because of towels nature ) "the new side cannot be smaller more then 60% of the original side size". Of couse, i would have some tolerance for the new size.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis one of the first idea was that and currently I'm working on something itthat but it sounded easier than it is. Plus, every idea is welcome.

Comment: Heheh, that is why we only have two different sizes of towels. <g> ... and two colors: blue and red.

Comment: Can you fold a towel in thirds (or other non-half proportions)?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you fold a towel in half, we can (in Theoryland) say that you perfectly cut some dimension of the towel in half (let’s ignore the fact for now that there’s some extra shrinkage due to the material bending around the crease).

So imagine you have a towel of dimension (2^k m, 2^r n) where k and r are natural numbers and m and n are odd integers. Then we can essentially ignore the 2^k and 2^r terms when trying to align the towels because we can always divide those terms out by folding in half as many times as we’d like.

Essentially, this means that we can just focus on the dimensions of the towels after you’ve divided out all the powers of two from their widths and heights. If the remaining dimensions of all the towels agree, then it’s always possible to fold all the towels so that they match. Just align them based on their reduced forms, find the smallest power of two that divides each axis, and fold all the towels precisely enough times to get them all to have exactly equal sizes.

On the other hand, if the reduced sizes don’t match, then no matter how you fold things they’ll never end up having the same size, and you’re out of luck.